# NP hard (like KNAPSACK)- any approximation scheme?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, np-complete

For a given set $S = \{1, 2, ... , N \}$, each component $i\in S$ can be represented by a triple $(a_i, b_i, c_i)$. How can the following be solved? Any polynomial time algorithm exists?

$$\max_{S' \subseteq S} \left(\sum_{k\in S'} a_k \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{k\in S'} b_k \right) $$
subject to $$\sum_{k\in S'} c_k \leq C. $$

If the objective function is $\sum_{k\in S'} a_k$, it's KNAPSACK, and there's an efficient polynomial algorithm. I don't have any idea if there's any method to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this *quadratic knapsack problem* via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in S$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i\in S'$.  For $1\le i < j \le N$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ represent $x_i x_j$.  The problem is to maximize
$$\sum_i a_i b_i x_i + \sum_{i < j} (a_i b_j + a_j b_i)y_{i,j}$$
subject to
\begin{align}
y_{i,j} &\le x_i &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag1\\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag2\\
y_{i,j} &\ge x_i + x_j - 1 &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag3\\
\sum_i c_i x_i &\le C \tag4
\end{align}
If all $a_i$ and $b_i$ are nonnegative, you can omit $(3)$.