# Knapsack, but divided by summation

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, np-complete, linearization

For a given set $S = \{1, 2, ... , N \}$, each component $i\in S$ can be represented by $(a_i, b_i, c_i, w_i)$. Is there any technique for solving the following problem?

$$\max_{S' \subseteq S} \frac{ \left(\sum_{k\in S'} a_k \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{k\in S'} b_k \right) }{\left(\sum_{k\in S'} c_k \right)}$$
subject to $$\sum_{k\in S'} w_k \leq C. $$

If the objective function is not divided by $\left(\sum_{k\in S'} c_k \right)$, it's QUADRATIC-KNAPSACK, which can be solved. How can this be solved?

Comment: this is trivial with mixed integer optimization if you add an extra variable $t$ and the constraint $\sum_{k \in S'} c_k t=1$, since you can cope with products of binary variables, and the product of binary and continuous variables

Comment: The first step of @LinAlg’s hint is called a Charnes-Cooper transformation.

Comment: @RobPratt not quite, unlike CC you don't need to change any of the other variables in this case

Comment: @LinAlg you’re going to multiply the denominator by $t$ but not the numerator?

Comment: @RobPratt After introducing $t$ the objective becomes $(a^Tx)(b^Tx)t$ with $x$ the binary variable that indicates the elements in $S'$. The second step in CC is substituting $y_i = x_i t$ and $z_i = x_i t$ so the objective becomes $(a^Ty)(b^Tz)/t$. That second step is counterproductive because then you need $y_i \in \{0,t\}$ instead of $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, and the objective is a nonconvex mess. Instead of this second step of CC, you can just process $(a^Tx)(b^Tx)t$ with the usual tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First linearize the numerator as shown in my answer to [NP hard (like KNAPSACK)- any approximation scheme?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875132/np-hard-like-knapsack-any-approximation-scheme/3875250#3875250).
Then apply [Charnes-Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming) as shown in my answer to [Doing a Charnes-Cooper transformation with matrices and an zero-one constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500493/doing-a-charnes-cooper-transformation-with-matrices-and-an-zero-one-constraint).